# go back from activity to fragment in android

Tags: android

I have a two class named Stock Details extends Fragment and another one is Stock info extends activity,
when I was trying to go back to my Stock details pages from Stock info pages it shows "Unfortunately,Application has stopped",but in my program I use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,StockDetails.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```

for go back to fragment. but it does not work. help me to solve this problem
I am the beginner for android.
kindly help me to go back from an Activity to fragment

Comment: you've got some fundamental issues that clearly shows you haven't even bothered to read a tutorial

Comment: @palanivel raghul .... Try to read some fundementals on fragment lifecycle and how it is used ..... Your question is unclear to answer,

Comment: sorry bro,I can go from Fragment to activity but i can't able to go back from activity to fragment so, My question is, how to go back from activity to particular fragment?

Comment: @palanivelraghul once AGAIN...read a tutorial, your question and comments make NO sense...the question title is very intriguing mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not need to start activity for StoreDetail as it is a subclass of **Fragment** not **Activity**.This is the reason that your app is crashed.

Now moving to your question if you want to go back to the fragment from the activty : Stock INFO you just need to call **finish()**  it will finish the current activity(Stock Info) and the fragment which is in background will be resumed.I had same problem and solved by this way .This is the onCreate Method of Activity(in your case it is for StockInfo class).Have a look:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setmCallBack(new IResultCallback() {
        @Override
        public void result(Result lastResult) {

            if (lastResult!=null) {
                finish();// by this line I have killed the current activity

            }
            else
            {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NotScan: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok look,

```
startActivity(intent);
```

this method name startActivity. So it will start another activity not fragment.
You can See & read the fragment: 
    http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: i understood but, i  have use previous activity as Navigation Drawer, in its i have inflated many fragments. I want to go back to    Navigation Drawer with particular Fragment? advance thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add fragment to go back to manually to the backstack.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
YourFragmentName myFragment = new YourFragmentName();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

And There is several methods here. Just take a look:-

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to the fragment , you can do this :

getFragmentManager().popBackStack();